# Records saving multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying save records in database, saved successfully but when i Clicking save button, every time records saving in table. i mean one record saved multiple times.

```
 public void saveEmployeeDetails(Employee employeeDetails){

   try{
       System.out.println("----saveEmployeeDetails----");          

       getSession().saveOrUpdate(employeeDetails);

       }
       catch (Exception e) {               
           e.printStackTrace();           
    }
}
```

i want save only one time. what is wrong in my code?

java class

```
public class Employee { 
private long id;
private String empid;
private String empname; 

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getEmpid() {
    return empid;
}
public void setEmpid(String empid) {
    this.empid = empid;
}
public String getEmpname() {
    return empname;
}
public void setEmpname(String empname) {
    this.empname = empname;
}   
}
```

hbm file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="org.hibernatejavaapp.Employee" table="EMP_DETAILS">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="empid" column="EMPID" type="string" length="255" not-null="true" />
    <property name="empname" column="EMPNAME" type="string" length="255" not-null="true" />     
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you share your Employee class, looks like its primary key changes for every save.

Comment: your question is not clear to provide an answer. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: with same id in database

Comment: show us your code for this transaction

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses `id` of an entity for the Object equlaity.in your case the same object is getting saved but with differend `id.` If you want to prevent the duplicate entry in your db for your issue.please override the `equals()` and `hashcode()` method in your entity class.Here you are using `saveUpdate()` so it Calls either `save()` or `update()` on the basis of identifier exists or not. e.g if identifier exists, update() will be called or else `save()` will be called.

**Its my Assumption based on your question if this is not the issue then please post your complete code.**

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like you should empId as your primary key. Surrogate keys should be used when your data modal do not have any business key.
If you do that then for a given employee hibernate will not insert multiple records for a given employee.

Your id is changing every time for a given employee which is causing many inserts.